# Limiting distribution of a ratio using Basu's theorem

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, convergence, uniform-distribution

Edit: there's seems to be a typo in original question.

This is a past exam question that I'm trying to solve. Suppose that $X_1,\ldots, X_n$ are i.i.d. Uniform (0, $\theta$) random variables. Let $X_{n:n} = \max_{1 \leq i \leq n} X_i.$

Find the limiting distribution of:
$$\frac{2\sum_{i=1}^n X_i - \theta}{\sqrt{n}X_{n:n}},$$
as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Here's what I've been able to do:

- 1) Can show that the limiting distribution of $X_{n:n}$ is $\theta$ by working on the CDF of $X_{n:n}$ as $n$ tends to infinity;
- 2) Using Basu's Theorem, I was able to show that $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i/\theta$ is independent of $X_{n:n}$ since the distribution of $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i/\theta$ is independent of $\theta$ and is thus an ancillary statistic. I was also able to show that $X_{n:n}$ was a boundedly complete sufficient statistic.

I can thus work on the initial term to get the following:
$$\frac{2\sum_{i=1}^n X_i - \theta}{\sqrt{n}X_{n:n}} = \frac{\theta}{X_{n:n}}\frac{\left(2 \sum_{i=1}^n X_i/\theta - 1\right)}{\sqrt{n}}.$$
From 1), I know that $\theta/X_{n:n}$ converges in distribution to 1. But, for the second term $\frac{\left(2 \sum_{i=1}^n X_i/\theta - 1\right)}{\sqrt{n}}$, I'm not able to find a limiting distribution. I tried to use the CLT, but without any success. Is my work so far wrong? Thanks for your help.

Comment: the scaling of the sum is incorrect... and the call to Basu's theorem does not seem right, since $\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}/\theta$ is not a statistic, being also a function of $\theta$.

Comment: What do you mean the scaling of the sum is incorrect? I don't see my mistake, I'm sorry. You have a good point as for the call of the Basu's theorem, $\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i/\theta$ can't be a statistic since it depends on $\theta$. I'm quite lost on what I should do. How would go about computing the following expectation: $E(\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i/X_{n:n}).$ I used a similar method than in my question in order to be able to use Basu's theorem.

Answer (score 4):

If one applies the CLT to $$\bar{X}_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$$it implies that
$$\sqrt{n}\left(\bar{X}_n-\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\longrightarrow \mathcal{N}(0,\theta^2/12)$$
Further,$$\frac{X_{n:n}}{\theta}\stackrel{\text{a.s.}}{\longrightarrow}1$$This should be enough to conclude. I believe the question as expressed 
$$\frac{2\sum_{i=1}^n X_i - \theta}{\sqrt{n}\,X_{n:n}}$$contains a typo and it should instead be
$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (2X_i - \theta)}{\sqrt{n}\,X_{n:n}}$$

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm sorry but I don't understand how this solves the problem. I understand that the CLT implies the convergence in distribution of $\sqrt{n}\left(\bar{X}_{n} - \theta/2\right)$ to a gaussian of zero mean and variance of $\theta^{2}/12$. What I don't understand is how to use the CLT in my problem. For example: $\frac{\left(2 \sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i - \theta \right)}{\sqrt{n}X_{n:n}} = ... = \frac{\sqrt{n}2\left( \bar{X}_{n} - \theta/2n\right)}{X_{n:n}}$.  My issue is with the term $\theta/2n$, I'm not able to get only $\theta/2$.

Comment: Your expression as given diverges almost surely.

Comment: Great thank you very much, this confirms my belief that there's indeed a typo in the question, or else it's not possible to use the CLT.